# not working fancy box slider properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, fancybox

I am working php application with code igniter framework and have attached fancybox js with the application. 
this is my view file.

```
<?php foreach ($item['items'] as $key => $value): ?>
    <li>
        <a style="text-decoration:none;" 
            data-fancybox="<?php echo $value['group']; ?>" 
            href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/products/<?php echo @$value['images'][0]; ?>">
            <?php echo $value['name']; ?>
        </a>
    </li>
    <!-- <div> -->
    <?php  unset($value['images'][0]); ?> 
    <?php if (empty(!$value['images'])) :?> 
        <?php foreach ($value['images'] as $img): ?>
            <a data-fancybox="printer" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/products/<?php echo $img; ?>"></a>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <!-- </div> -->
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I need view

```
href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/products/<?php echo $img; ?>"
```

in fancybox view but when I click slider items it is only view one image and not display movement arrow. my url display like this

```
http://localhost/technet/products#printers
```

how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Show your jquery code where you have initialize fancybox?

Comment: using fancyBox v3.1.28

Comment: may I need link to fancybox js file to with view file?

Comment: Yes ofcourse, Can you show little more code here?

Comment: in my view file I have only **<a data-fancybox="printer" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/products/<?php echo $img; ?>"></a>** witch related to fancy box

Comment: in my question have my view file

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fancybox.init();
});` You have to add this script in bottom of view file

Comment: where should I put this code in my view file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156313/discussion-between-naim-malek-and-john).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to help you without seeing your live page or at least seeing what html code you have. Because, how can we know what your php code produces?

I can only guess that `<?php echo $value['group']; ?>` outputs something different for each link and therefore grouping is not working.

Comment: I have issue with **<a data-fancybox="printer" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/products/<?php echo $img; ?>"></a>**